# Can I use setIn to create a new index on an empty array?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My problem is, using inmutable in this structure:

```
myMap = Map({a: [], b: []});
myMAp.setIn(['a', 0], 'v');
```

this is getting an exception

```
immutable.js:870 Uncaught (in promise) Error: invalid keyPath
    at invariant (immutable.js:870)
    at updateInDeepMap (immutable.js:1974)
    at updateInDeepMap (immutable.js:1980)
    at Map.updateIn (immutable.js:1278)
    at Map.setIn (immutable.js:1256)
```

I know I can check if such index exist, initialize if not, then try the update, but maybe a feature request is feasible so inmutable let do this on one step. I don't see any motive for inmutable raising an exception on this use case.
I'm reading the library spec on http://untangled.io/immutable-js-all-the-examples-youll-ever-need-to-get-set-and-delete-data-from-lists/
And what I propose is what is normal on lists:

> If an index doesn’t exist anywhere in the keyPath, then List.setin()
>   will do one of the following:
>
> If the index preceding the bad index references a List, then the bad
>   index is trying to insert a value at a place outside of the bounds of
>   this list. Usual rules apply, and the List expands, the value is
>   placed at the end of the expanded List, and nulls are inserted in
>   between. Try it for yourself in the example below, by replacing the
>   last line with avengersList.setIn([1, 1, 1, 3], 'scarletWitch'); If
>   the index preceding the bad index is a value (i.e. not a List or Map),
>   then the bad index is trying to insert a value into a data type that
>   has no concept of an index; accordingly, an Invalid keyPath error will
>   be thrown. Try it for yourself in the example below, by replacing the
>   last line with avengersList.setIn([0, 1], 'scarletWitch');. This tries
>   to insert ‘scarletWitch’ into the String ‘ironMan’, and that’s never
>   going to work!

Comment: There is no reason to use `setIn` here. The arrays are mutable. So you can actually do `myMap.get('a')[0] = 'v'`. Of course that's gross. Do you actually have `Immutable.List`s instead of arrays?

Answer (score 1):

Your question doesn't exactly make sense because you're saying you  want to create a new index inside a List, but you're trying to access a `keyPath` that doesn't exist (it's an empty array, so it doesn't have a `[0]` index yet), but the object property does exist that holds this `keyPath`, so that's what you'd want to use, and you'd want to `updateIn` and not `setIn`. Here's what I think it would look like :

```
//a doesn't have to be an `Immutable.List`, it can be a plain JS array
var myMap = Immutable.Map({a: Immutable.List([]), b: []}) 
var Rogelio = myMap.updateIn(['a'], list => list.push(0))
console.log(Rogelio)
```

Comment: thanks for your response. I was thinking incorrectly that on creating a Map with a complicated json as source, including arrays, those convert automatically to List, and objects convert to Maps, but it seems that is not the case.

Comment: Read the docs, I need fromJS() for a deep conversion of Objects and arrays to Maps and Lists

Comment: So did this not answer the question?

Comment: yes, your answer is a way to do it and I've upvoted it, but mine is more accurate on what I'm doing

Answer (score 1):

first incorrect assumption: `Map` constructor makes a deep conversion from objects and arrays to `Maps` and `Lists`. You need `fromJS` function for this.

```
    //const { fromJS, Map, List } = require('immutable');
    myMap = fromJS({a: [], b: []});
    var myMap2 = myMap.setIn(['a', 0], 'v');
    console.log(myMap2);
```

second posible error. Consider that setIn do some change on **inmutable** myMap. The cloned results of setIn must go to a new variable if you are want to do something with the changed structure (as saving on new state).